# SMTP to Gmail: image corrupted by added CRLFs

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, smtp, gmail

I'm writing a Python script to set up a socket to send a multipart email with an image from my Gmail account via SMTP. I am not using smtplib or email.mime for educational purposes. I'm using ssl and socket and wrapping a TCP socket with ssl.wrap_socket.

Everything works fine and the email arrives with both text and an attached image. However, the attached JPEG image is corrupted.

Comparing the original image and the corrupted image in a hex editor, I can see that all of the 0x0D and 0x0A bytes in the jpeg have been replaced by 0x0D0x0A. These bytes would represent CR and LF in text, so it appears that at some point, CR and LF are being replaced by CRLF inappropriately in my binary data.

The binary data appears to be correct if I write it to a file immediately before I send it into the ssl socket. Gmail appears to be correctly interpreting the Content-type, as it displays the corrupted image as an image.

Any ideas where CRLF replacement might be creeping into binary image data?

Solution:

The relevant solution code for the encoding header:

```
        b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +\
```

And for the base64 encoding itself:

```
clientSocketSSL.sendall(base64.b64encode(msgImage))
```

Comment: Maybe you should use higher level modules if you don't want to learn all the details of the protocol and let it do the "right stuff". If you do want to use sockets, then dig into the MIME RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't show any code my guess is that you simple put the binary image into the mail. But, traditionally mail can only transport ASCII data and has a line length limitation of 1000 characters so the data has to be encoded for transport, see [Wikipedia:MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for more infornation.

If you don't specify any encoding for transport it will be treated as 7bit and if you are lucky as 8bit encoding and both of these encodings treat line ends special and will change it depending on the platform. This means on Windows a original single LF will be stored as CRLF and on Unix a original CRLF will be stored as LF only. Note that not only the sending and receiving mail user agents might adapt the data to the platform but any mail server in between might change these too.

In summary: use MIME to properly encode binary data for transport, [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) provides the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about encoding. See my edits above for what I've done so far but I'll keep investigating this.

Comment: @TonyM: it's exactly like I expected, i.e. no proper transport-safe encoding like base64. Apart from that you should treat email as bytes and not as UTF-8 encoded data.